# Creating a qualification ladder/flow chart/tree

Tags: flow-charts

I'm trying to set up an easy way to create a sports qualification/elimination ladder like e.g. this: http://www.raceamerica.com/download/ladders/ladr32p.pdf

I'll take care of the contents programmatically, but looking for an easy, dynamic way of creating the actual layout of the tree. Each node might be filled with text data, or remain empty.

I tried some examples I found using TikZ/Forest or basic TikZ stuff, but most of the examples didn't work out the way I needed them (e.g. with the boxes not being placed nicely vertically centered between the two preceding boxes). 
I've also tried putting my own macros together (I'm a bit rusty, f* you, M$ Office!), but haven't come too far yet.

The output does not have to look exactly like that, as long as the basic structure comes out like that and I can fill the nodes with my data (probably small table or two-liner)

Can anyone suggest some macro package to solve this? Non-LaTeX (PlainTeX) preferred, but will not be picky if it is something that requires LaTeX as long as it works ... ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Ti*k*Z/PGF. Ticks all the boxes. Sounds like it isn't a tree (haven't followed the link to look), especially if the tree-ish packages are no good. Works with plain or LaTeX. Well-documented. Not really sure what's to be said here without more details about the problem you want help with e.g. what you tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you mean by "with the boxes not being placed nicely vertically centered between the two preceding boxes".

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={
    grow=180,
    draw,
    fork sep=8pt,
    text width=15mm,
    minimum height=5mm,
    parent anchor=west,
    child anchor=east,
    text centered,
  }
[
 [
  [
   [
    [
     []
     [,fill]
    ]
    [
     []
     []
    ]
   ]
   [
    [
     []
     []
    ]
    [
     []
     []
    ]
   ]
  ]
  [
   [
    [
     []
     []
    ]
    [
     []
     []
    ]
   ]
   [
    [
     []
     []
    ]
    [
     []
     []
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
 [,fill
  [,fill
   [,fill
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
   ]
   [,fill
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
   ]
  ]
  [,fill
   [,fill
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
   ]
   [,fill
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
    [,fill
     [,fill]
     [,fill]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The sample I had - which I changed somewhat - somehow ended up with the second/third level nodes remaining at their position, while the height in the first level had changed, leading to the tree looking pretty weird ... will run your sample through TeX later on, looks pretty simple ... Tnx!

Comment: @user214 If that answer works for you, you may consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it.

Comment: Looks good, did some initial tests ... tnx ... layout still looks a bit off if the contents in the boxes has different heights ... will do some further tests that are somewhat more like real-life tests ...

Comment: After having at least the basic functionality implemented, I tried getting this to work with plain TeX, but Forest seems to be LaTeX only, is that right? Can only find the LaTeX .sty files and stuff, no plain .tex macro files ... or am I missing something here? I never got into LaTeX but rather used a stack of other macro libraries and own macros to do what I wanted ... if all I needed was the tree I could probably just stick to LaTeX for this, but I need to do some more with the page, and I'm not really happy having to get into LaTeX coding just to use the Forest macros :(

Comment: @GarryG I am sorry, I never worked with plain TeX. (I know that Ti*k*Z should work with TeX, but I am not sure about forest.

Comment: After some fiddling, I managed to get what I needed put together ... as my requirements were rather low (only a single page which mainly consists of the tree, plus some lead-in and a signature line), I was able to steer around all the problems I personally have with LaTeX ;) and get a decent looking output ... I probably wouldn't want to have to do a whole article or book with it, but in this case, all's good and I can get back to the actual work ... :) (and from what I can discern, Forest does not seem to exist for Plain TeX ...)
Thanks @all for the help!

Comment: @GarryG Glad to hear! You can always ask a follow-up question, if you are lucky, cfr or Alan Munn are going to answer it, so you'll get something really cool. ;-)